# Maximize AUC of a classifier having a set of probabilities that the object belongs to class

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability

Consider a binary classification task with two target classes -- {men, women}. For each person you've got a set of their actions and for each action you've got a set of real-valued features. The goal is to classify persons into men/women with the highest possible AUC.

The easiest approach is to train a classifier that predicts whether particular action belongs to man or woman (indeed, as we have features for actions, we can train a classifier without any additional work).

The question is how to derive the probability of being man or woman based on the probabilities for each of your actions to belong to man or woman?

Comment: You can also compute different statistics of each user's actions, and use it as a fixed-size feature vector in a classifier.